What does it mean by x-byte aligned in 32 bit system?
It is said that data/instruction starting address should be a multiple of it's size and if it is so, we call it x-byte aligned where x is size of data/instruction in memory. Why it should be like this? Let's take an example. We have a double value i.e. 8 bytes. On 32 bit system, we have word size = 4 bytes. It makes sense to have starting address to be a multiple of 4 (for better performance as CPU fetches data/instructions according to word size). But in reality, it's starting address should be a multiple of 8. Can anyone help me on this?
I guess, the starting address should be a multiple of word size.

x86 machine code is a byte stream of variable-width instructions. Real CPUs fetch it from L1i cache in chunks of 16 (Intel since PPro) or 32 bytes (some AMD CPUs, IIRC).  8-byte alignment for branch targets within functions is a tradeoff between not wasting too much space and not having the worst case where you're jumping to the last couple bytes of a 16-byte block so the first fetch doesn't get many useful bytes. See Agner Fog's microarch doc for more details about how CPUs fetch machine code, especially older ones before the uop cache made it matter much less

It's not very meaningful to say that the "word size" of a 32-bit x86 CPU is 4 bytes.  Certainly not in terms of instruction fetch (Are machine code instructions fetched in little endian 4-byte words on an Intel x86-64 architecture? / https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/2/), only for integer data loaded / stored to general-purpose registers (not SIMD).  Since P5 Pentium we have guaranteed atomicity for aligned loads/stores up to 8 bytes, for example.

Sort of a duplicate of Why should code be aligned to even-address boundaries on x86? but the answers there only make sense for 386/486, suggesting that 4-byte alignment is the most that matters!  But Jim Mischel's does have an example of what it looks like in asm.  Another related question for data: Memory alignment on a 32-bit Intel processor

But in reality, it's starting address should be a multiple of 8 - Where did you get this "fact" from anyway?  What was the original context?


… data/instruction starting address should be a multiple of [its] size…

That is not a true statement.
Computer hardware commonly has characteristics that favor or require certain alignments for instructions or various kinds of data. These alignments are not always multiples of the size of the instruction or the data.
One common reason for an alignment requirement is that the hardware to transfer data between main memory and the processor transfers a group of, say, g bytes at a time (possibly because it has 8g wires for transferring 8g bits), and the hardware is designed to address memory only in groups of g bytes, so every memory location accessed using this transfer mechanism has an address that is a multiple of g.
With such a design, you want to ensure that any data item that is g bytes or smaller fits into one of those groups. So you do not want it to start in one group of g bytes and finish in a different group. If g is 4, you want a 4-byte object to start at addresses 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, and so on, any multiple of 4. For a two-byte object, you want it to start at addresses 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, and so on. Although you could have a 2-byte object that started at address 1 and occupied bytes at addresses 1 an 2, and that would fit into the 4-byte group from bytes 0 to 3, inclusive, you would then have a problem with an array of these 2-byte objects, because the next one would start at byte 3 and go to byte 4, thus splitting across the 0-3 group and the 4-7 group.
So, for an object smaller than g bytes, we still want its alignment to be a multiple of that object’s size, so that arrays of it work nicely with the grouping. (I am implicitly assuming all these objects have sizes that are powers of two but will not cover that in detail.)
For an object larger than g bytes, it does not necessarily have to start on a multiple of its size. Consider an object that is 8 bytes on a system with 4-byte grouping. Since it is 8 bytes long, it cannot fit into one 4-byte group. So we want the next best possibility, that it fits into two groups and not three. If it starts at 0, 4, 8, 12, and so on, any multiple of 4, it will fit into two groups. For example, if it starts at byte 4, it will run from bytes 4 to 11, inclusive, fitting into groups 4-7 and 8-11. So 4-byte alignment is good for an 8-byte object on this system. If it started at, say, byte 6, it would run from 6 to 13 and be groups 4-7, 8-11, and 12-15, which is not good.
So, a system can be designed so that 8-byte objects only need 4-byte alignment. This is why the statement “data/instruction starting address should be a multiple of [its] size” is not true.”
Additionally, on Intel’s IA-32 architecture, instructions have various sizes but do not have any alignment requirements (or, equivalently, the alignment requirement is 1 byte, meaning they can start on any address).
As mentioned initially, there are various characteristics that can affect alignment requirements. A processor may be designed to allow “misaligned” objects, and the processor will simply transfer as many groups of data to or from memory as needed. Then it may be favorable for an object to have a good alignment but not be required. On the other hand, a processor might be designed so that some instructions for working with certain eight-byte objects never use the low three bits of an address, so the instructions only work with objects that are eight-byte aligned, even though the memory transfer hardware could handle four-byte alignment.
In summary, the alignment requirements for instructions and for various data types depend on multiple factors, and the alignment requirement for an instruction or for a data type is not necessarily a multiple of its size.
Note also that an alignment requirement might be favored but not required. On a system that supports loading and storing misaligned objects, both aligned and misaligned objects will work, but performance will be better with aligned objects.
This gets complicated further when you consider a C implementation. Per the C standard, objects in C implementations have alignment requirements. Most often, C implementations are designed to be efficient for their target architecture(s), so the alignment requirements the C implementation imposes for its objects will mirror the required alignments in the hardware and likely will also mirror the favored alignments in the hardware. However, a C implementation would be allowed by the standard to impose stricter requirements than the hardware requires. It could also have laxer requirements than the hardware requires, which it would implement by generating the instructions necessary to load objects in parts. This is rare, but it is something a C implementation might do to support old software written for a different system.

Note the question is tagged x86, so alignment doesn't matter for correctness (never need extra instructions for unaligned loads/stores, except with SSE SIMD then you can't use addps xmm, [esi], you need a separate movups load.)  But alignment can matter for performance up to 16 or 32-byte vector width, or for 64-byte cache lines (or AVX-512 vector width).  (Or 32-byte chunks of machine code for uop-cache lines or on some CPUs for fetch blocks.)  So in that sense C implementations are stricter than the HW, but for performance i386 SysV is also laxer, having alignof(double)==4
